# How to display * symbol in a label when the associated UIInput is not required in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I need to display an asterisk (*) symbol in front of a PrimeFaces label with the same style as required symbol while the required attribute of the associated UIInput is not set to `true`. I know that in PrimeFaces 6.0 there is an attribute named `pfRequired` that does what I want, but I'm using PrimeFaces 6.1 and I don't want to downgrade. The usage of `pfRequired` is like this:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Name: " for="username" />
<p:inputText id="username" pfRequired="#{true}" />
```

By the way in some frameworks including Oracle ADF, there is an attribute named `showRequired` that does the same. How can I do it in PrimeFaces 6.1 without developing an extended `OutputLabelRenderer`?

Comment: Where did you read about `pfRequired`?

Comment: @Kukeltje I expected such feature and I tracked it down in PrimeFaces source code in `OutputLabelRenderer` class. But unfortunately, it no longer exists in PrimeFaces 6.1.

Comment: Did you try to add a class to the label and style it with css?

Comment: @Kukeltje No, I didn't. Actually, I believe adding a style class to label doesn't add an asterisk to the label.

Comment: But how is the asterisk implemented if it really is required?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar There is a method named `encodeRequiredIndicator` in `OutputLabelRenderer` that writes an asterisk in `ResponseWriter`; this method is called when the `UIInput` mentioned in `for` attribute is required.

Comment: Alright I did'nt realize you need a generic solution.. In that case my guess would be you need the renderer

Comment: yes, you need to customize the renderer (extend amd create your own one). You can add content via css (adding an asterisk) but not style it (make it red).

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you. I hope PrimeFaces brings back `pfRequired` to its next version.

Comment: If you don't file an issue, I don't think it will (seems to have been an non-official feature)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you for reminding it. I will file an issue then.

Comment: No need to... https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2854

Comment: @Kukeltje Good news. The issue is created and resolved 2 days ago when I posted this question :) thanks to Thomas Andraschko. BTW, would you post the link to the issue and some of its text as an answer; I think this question is worth having an answer.

Comment: You can and are encouraged even to create your own answers (provided the Q and A are 'good') which at least up to now the Q here is. I'll 'edit' your A if relevant...

Comment: @Kukeltje Actually, I had created my issue in github before I read your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, as @Kukeltje mentioned in comments, an issue has been created and resolved in github to meet this requirement:

[OutputLabel: add possiblity to always display the required indicator](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2854)

> Currently we have an attribute called "indicateRequired".
>   True (default) means that the it's displayed when the component is required or @NotNull is present.
>   False means that it's never displayed.
>
> The easiest way it the following now:
>   Auto (default) means that the it's displayed when the component is required or @NotNull is present.
>   true mean that it's always displayed
>   False means that it's never displayed.

The milestone of the issue has not been determined yet. The usage sample will be like this:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Name: " for="username" />
<p:inputText id="username" indicateRequired="true" />
```

Comment: Since there already is a commit done, it most likely will be at least in 6.2 and maybe in the upcoming 6.1.8 elite release to.